# How to parse bbcodes safely?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to parse BBcodes in php but i don't think my code is safe at all.

```
$Text = preg_replace("(\[color=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/color\])is","<span style=\"color: $1\">$2</span>",$Text);
```

I think you can pass an injection like this and it will work:

```
[color=<script>alert('gotcha');</script>]...[/color]
```

How to improve my regex to only capture the two standar color formats:

```
[color=red]...[/color] OR [color=#FF0000]...[/color]
```

Thanks

Comment: To mask html tags all you need is replace all `<` with `&lt;`

Comment: BBCode is not a regular language and thus you cannot use a regular expression to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

PHP actually has [built-in support for bbcode](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) (though you'll need to install a PECL extension).

Alternatively, there is a [PEAR library HTML_BBCodeParser](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser) that you can use.

I would recommend using one of the above solutions instead of writing your own as they have been community tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\[color=((([a-zA-Z])+)|(\#[A-F0-9]{1,6})))
```

I think that's the idea, my regex is a little rusty (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to write your own bbcode parser, it's best to take some time to write a decent [Recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for it.

This because you must be sure that the bbcode is properly formatted and nested, having a random  in your code can break the layout. You must take care to remove any javascript:// protocol identifiers in the links. And take take to only go over a string once to avoid double encoding ([b[b]bold me[/b]]me too[/b]). The list goes on and is beyond simple regexes to get completely right.