# Getting key and value from string

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

```
<?php
// This is my string
$input = "Lorum ipsum [tag=foo]dolor[/tag] sit [tag=bar]amet[/tag] consectetur adipiscing elit.";

// This is my pattern
$pattern = "~\[tag=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/tag\]~s";

// This should output all tags with it's value
$output = preg_split($pattern, $input);
print_r($output);
?>
```

It outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Lorum ipsum [1] => sit [2] => consectetur adipiscing elit. )
```

But I want:

```
Array ( 
  [foo] => dolor,
  [bar] => amet
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $output);` instead.

Comment: It looks like bbcode. If it is, various parsers already exist for that. You may already know this, but I wanted to mention it just in case.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16505377/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/9900385/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/2661081/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15998847/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which will apply the given pattern multiple times to find all the matches across the string, and accumulate them into output variable (which is the third parameter) in an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [tag=foo]dolor[/tag]
            [1] => [tag=bar]amet[/tag]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => dolor
            [1] => amet
        )

)
```

where index `[0]` has all the matches for the whole regular expression, index `[1]` has the matches for the first capturing group (parentheses) in the pattern, and `[2]` for the second.

All you need then is to combine arrays in `[1]` and `[2]` into one, so the values from `[1]` went into keys and from `[2]` into values of the new array. That could be done using [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine)

```
<?php
$input = "Lorum ipsum [tag=foo]dolor[/tag] sit [tag=bar]amet[/tag] consectetur adipiscing elit.";

$pattern = "~\[tag=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/tag\]~s";

// This should output all tags with it's value
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $regexpresult)) {
  $output = array_combine($regexpresult[1], $regexpresult[2]);
  print_r($output);
}
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => dolor
    [bar] => amet
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use preg_match_all to get this type of index , 0 index in array are the matches, 1 index are the tag names and 2 index are the tag values.
1 and 2 index have the same exact position of the key values you require.

```
<?php
// This is my string
$input = "Lorum ipsum [tag=foo]dolor[/tag] sit [tag=bar]amet[/tag] consectetur adipiscing elit.";

// This is my pattern
$pattern = "~\[tag=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/tag\]~s";

// This should output all tags with it's value
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $output);
print_r($output);

OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [tag=foo]dolor[/tag]
            [1] => [tag=bar]amet[/tag]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => dolor
            [1] => amet
        )

)
```